# How to convert streaming DataFrame into regular batch DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to convert streaming data frame into normal data frame for doing a lot of operation :
count.distinct
complex queries for real time analytics.

Please suggest , if you have any idea about conversion of streaming data frame to normal data frame in spark.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best bet is to write a custom streaming [Sink](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Sink.scala) and have access to a `DataFrame` every batch in `addBatch`.

`Sink` is fairly short so quoting the scaladoc and code here.

```
/**
 * An interface for systems that can collect the results of a streaming query. In order to preserve
 * exactly once semantics a sink must be idempotent in the face of multiple attempts to add the same
 * batch.
 */
trait Sink {

  /**
   * Adds a batch of data to this sink. The data for a given `batchId` is deterministic and if
   * this method is called more than once with the same batchId (which will happen in the case of
   * failures), then `data` should only be added once.
   *
   * Note 1: You cannot apply any operators on `data` except consuming it (e.g., `collect/foreach`).
   * Otherwise, you may get a wrong result.
   *
   * Note 2: The method is supposed to be executed synchronously, i.e. the method should only return
   * after data is consumed by sink successfully.
   */
  def addBatch(batchId: Long, data: DataFrame): Unit
}
```

Read also [StreamSinkProvider](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.sources.StreamSinkProvider).

Answer (score 1):

Save your streaming dataframe either to local or kafka. And read it in batch mode from local or kafka.

Comment: From local? How would that look like? Care to point me to the "sources"?